# Modify data before pagination in CakePhp

Tags: php, json, cakephp, pagination

I'm trying to create an Api using cakephp.
I generate a json on server and it works fine , but I tired to use pagination and I got a problem.

in the first case I take the image's path and I encode it to base64 and I generate json => works

in the second case I defined the pagination by the limits and the max and I kept the same code but as a result the image field is still the path from the database and it's not encoded

this my code in my controller :

```
class PilotsController extends AppController {
    public $paginate = [
        'page' => 1,
        'limit' => 5,
        'maxLimit' => 5
    ];

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        $this->Auth->allow(['add','edit','delete','view','count']);
    }

    public function view($id) {
        $pilot = $this->Pilots->find()->where(['Pilots.account_id' => $id], [
            'contain' => ['Accounts', 'Pilotlogs']
        ]);
        foreach ($pilot as $obj) {
            if ($obj->image_pilot!= NULL) {
                $image1 = file_get_contents(WWW_ROOT.$obj->image_pilot);
                $obj->image_pilot = base64_encode($image1);
            }
        }
        $this->set('pilot', $this->paginate($pilot));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['pilot']);
    }
}
```

If I remove the pagination from the code it works fine . Any idea how to fix it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a result formatter instead, ie `Query::formatResults()`.
So you'll have something like this :

```
public function view($id) {
$pilot = $this->Pilots->find()
->where(['Pilots.account_id' => $id], [
    'contain' => ['Accounts', 'Pilotlogs']]);
->formatResults(function($results) {
    return $results->map(function($row) {
        $image1 = file_get_contents(WWW_ROOT.$row['image_pilot']);
        $row['image_pilot'] = base64_encode($image1);
        return $row;
    });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply first paginate the data and then get the array values and after that modify that data as you want. Check this

```
public function view($id) {
    $pilot = $this->Pilots->find()->where(['Pilots.account_id' => $id], [
        'contain' => ['Accounts', 'Pilotlogs']
    ]);
    $pilot = $this->paginate($pilot);
    $pilot = $pilot->toArray();
    foreach ($pilot as $obj) {
        if ($obj->image_pilot!= NULL) {
            $image1 = file_get_contents(WWW_ROOT.$obj->image_pilot);
            $obj->image_pilot = base64_encode($image1);
        }
    }
    $this->set('pilot', $pilot);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['pilot']);
}
```

Comment: That's what [**result formatters**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields) are good for.